# How to fix "Cannot create property 'default' on boolean 'true'"

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I've installed a package that provides pagination component for vue. I've followed the documentation to set up everything correctly but I am getting this error that I have no idea how to fix.

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot create property 'default' on boolean 'true'"

[image: laravel-vue-pagination error]

This is how my response.data looks like:

[image: response-data]

Tried changing variables, hardcoding them but everything is out of desperation to fix it. I've used google but most of the results are in chinese or they are not working for my case.

```
<pagination :data="data">
    <span slot="prev-nav">&lt; Previous</span>
    <span slot="next-nav">Next &gt;</span>
</pagination>
```

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getResults()
    },
    methods: {
        getResults(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/api/reviews?page=' + page).then(response => {
                 this.data = response.data;
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Hopefully any of you have a solution.

Comment: How does your `response.data` look like? Please include that in your question.

Comment: @Terry i've included response.data. Thanks.

Comment: What package did you install? What does the code look like around the error? (in `ReviewsIndexComponent.vue`)

Comment: @tony19 I've installed https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination. Just a <table> element and after that I create <pagination>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel-vue-pagination there is a open PR similar to your problem 
with 'potential bug' tag 
here's [the link](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination/issues/44)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install laravel-vue-pagination@2.1.0 --save
```

This version would solve the issue